# how to change automatically UTC time to current local time in my web application.

Tags: mysql, timezone, utc

In my web application like eCommerce site. Every projects have time limit.I will display time left details in each and every projects.i am using UTC time.how to convert current localtime for every users.For example, USA have 4 or 5 different time zone.i am using php codeigniter and mysql for my web application

Comment: This is a broad discussion point, which has been discussed many times already.  Please search, read the existing answers, then ask if you have *specific* questions.  The [tag:timezone] or [tag:datetime] tags are widely applicable to this subject.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would keep all times on your server side UTC and only convert to local time in the client via JavaScript. However, dealing with client time is tricky, since you can't really know their wall time.

I have seen 3 approaches:

**1) Use `var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`**

Probably the best way of getting the client system timezone in an automatic fashion.

**2) Try to figure out the timezone by the client IP.**

If you need to do the time rendering on your server after all, this might me the only automatic way you can do it. It is very error prone though, because your clients might be using proxies, VPNs etc. Also, the geoIP databases might not be accurate enough.

**3) Let the user set the timezone.**

This is playing it safe. the user can decide. You can also kepp the setting in a cookie or such.

The [momentjs timezone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) might help you with all three approaches.

Comment: WRT #1, that only gets the *current offset*, not the time zone.  That doesn't help with server-side conversions, since the offset may change within the time zone for things like daylight saving time.  See "Time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: That is why I wrote client side. Getting the real time zone can be very tricky. I tend to let the user set it. I still think that the OP should keep the time to UTC on the server and only deal with time zone issues on the client side.